# Values saved in DB return different

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a Google Map App. `onLongClick()` marker is addded into two Lists. One is only with `LatLng` for future save in `sharedPrefferences` and the other one is being inserted into SQLite in `onDestroy()`. The problem is, that the `LatLng` i get back from the database is shorter in leght from that i have in the marker when i put it on the map. This makes my info activity to fail opening. 
This is my methods involved:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    markerOptions=getAddress(markerOptions);
    locations.add(latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude);
    databaseList.add(markerOptions);
}
```

from here `markerOptions` object goes to `List<MarkerOptions> databaseList`
and in `onDestroy()` the list goes to DB:

```
public void insertList(List<MarkerOptions> list) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
    for (MarkerOptions marker : list) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        String[] split = marker.getTitle().split(", ");
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, split[0]);
        values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, split[1]);
        values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.getPosition().latitude);
        values.put(COLUMN_LNG, marker.getPosition().longitude);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        values.clear();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Then in `onCreate()` i fill the same list with `markerOptions`:

```
public class DatabaseProcessThread extends AsyncTask<List<MarkerOptions>,Void,List<MarkerOptions>>{


    @Override
    protected List<MarkerOptions> doInBackground(List<MarkerOptions>... params) {
        SQLiteHelper db = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
        return db.getExistingMarkers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MarkerOptions> markerOptionses) {
        super.onPostExecute(markerOptionses);
        databaseList=markerOptionses;
    }
}
```

The problem is when i tested it with 4 markers, restarted the app and put one more on the map, the old 4 does not open cause they don't pass this `if`:

```
 @Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    for (MarkerOptions options : databaseList) {
        if (options.getPosition().latitude==marker.getPosition().latitude&&options.getPosition().longitude==marker.getPosition().longitude){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.fixxxer.map.MarkerActivity.class);
            Log.v(TAG,options.getPosition().toString());
            String[]split = options.getTitle().split(", ");
            intent.putExtra("Address",split[0]);
            intent.putExtra("Country",split[1]);
            intent.putExtra("Latitude",marker.getPosition().latitude);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude",marker.getPosition().longitude);
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,split[0]+","+split[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG,options.getPosition().toString());
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how i obtain the `markerOptions`:

```
public List<MarkerOptions> getExistingMarkers() {

    ArrayList<MarkerOptions> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
    Cursor curs = null;SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        curs = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        curs.moveToFirst();
        if (curs.isFirst()) {
            do {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.title(curs.getString(1) + ", " + curs.getString(2));
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(curs.getString(3)), Double.valueOf(curs.getString(4)));
                markerOptions.position(latlng);
                list.add(markerOptions);
                curs.moveToNext();
            } while (!curs.isAfterLast());
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    curs.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

`Log.v` on the all 5 locations returned:

`01-14 13:21:17.859 7841-7841/com.example.fixxxer.map V/MAPS ACTIVITY: lat/lng: (-16.9619,20.079)
01-14 13:21:17.859 7841-7841/com.example.fixxxer.map V/MAPS ACTIVITY: lat/lng: (-25.4685,23.4743)
01-14 13:21:17.859 7841-7841/com.example.fixxxer.map V/MAPS ACTIVITY: lat/lng: (1.3249,12.0056)
01-14 13:21:17.859 7841-7841/com.example.fixxxer.map V/MAPS ACTIVITY: lat/lng: (-29.0083,24.7622)
01-14 13:21:17.859 7841-7841/com.example.fixxxer.map V/MAPS ACTIVITY: lat/lng: (-4.444019301843549,27.22086824476719)`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you save different values in the database list and the locations list:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    markerOptions=getAddress(markerOptions);
    locations.add(latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude);
    databaseList.add(markerOptions);
}
```

Probably `markerOptions=getAddress(markerOptions);` leads to a value for the position in the database which is different to the actual marker on the map.

Comment: ` @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerOptions=getAddress(markerOptions);
        locations.add(markerOptions.getPosition().latitude + ", " + markerOptions.getPosition().longitude);
        databaseList.add(markerOptions);
    }`
Does't work again. `(42.6816,23.3622)` old one and `(42.68067903539401,23.361671045422554)`

Comment: @FixXxeR Try leaving `markerOptions=getAddress(markerOptions);` out. You overwrite the original position with the values returned from `getAddress(markerOptions)`.

Comment: Values are correct until they go to DB. After retrieval values are shorter.

Comment: List with `markerOptions` has been checked right before insert. All is fine before insertion. Any idea why?

Comment: Problem solved. For some reason `Double.valueOf(curs.getString(3)` is not equal to `curs.getDouble(3)`. Changed it and now all works well.